# NPM v5: Generate lockfile alongside `yarn.lock`?

Tags: npm, yarnpkg

I maintain a [starter kit](https://github.com/reactql/cli) that bundles a Yarn `yarn.lock` file.

Now that NPM v5 is released and recommends committing its own `package-lock.json`, I'd like to include both.

Is it possible to generate *both* files without actually installing anything, solely for the purpose of committing the locks?

Note: The reason for including both is that, as a starter kit, the end-user may choose to use Yarn or NPM. I have no control over their environment, so I'd like to support both out-the-box.